# What's the default job ordering for GitHub Actions workflows, and how to enforce that workflows are executed in FIFO manner?

Tags: github, github-actions

In Gitlab, two or more instances of the same pipeline may execute simultaneously, with their jobs executing as soon as their requirements are met.

To disable this behavior, I configure GitLab to use `process_mode=oldest-first`:

```
curl --request PUT --data "process_mode=oldest_first" \                                                                                                                                                                                      
--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "https://example.com/api/v4/projects/3465/resource_groups/deploy-release"
```

But what guarantees do GitHub Actions make regarding the execution of its workflows?

- How many workflows can execute at any time?
- How are jobs ordered between the workflow executions?
- How can I configure workflow execution?

Context:

Suppose I have a workflow with the following jobs: `test`, `build`, and `deploy`, where `deploy` runs a reusable workflow. I will naturally configure the jobs to `needs` on each other, with `deploy` having `concurrency` of 1. Still, I want to guaranteee that the `deploy` job in the first workflow execution always runs first.

Comment: What do you mean concurrency of 1? It's a _group_: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#example-requiring-successful-dependent-jobs)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean the `deploy` job is configured with `concurrency: 1`, so that only one instance of it may run at a time

Comment: @Pieterjan This doesn't explain how jobs are executed, when multiple instances of the same workflow are executed simultaneously?